# Regular Expression for a valid DB Table Name

Tags: javascript

I need to create a table in DB through java code.
    I am taking the name from user through a form.
    Please can u tell me the Regular Expression which resist the user to enter a valid Table Name?

```
For Example in DB if we create a table with (" ")space it will not allow.
```

Comment: Is it even possible to create a table with a white-space in its name??

Comment: @matewka This is the point of this question, restricting user to input the proper table name. However, table names with spaces are allowed, at least in SQL Server and Oracle - it is considered bad practice though.

Answer (score 0):

Try this 
[a-zA-Z\d][\w#@]{0,127}$

128 Characters, 
No spaces
case insensitive